# Signal R works on background using iPhone Simulator but doesnt on real device + Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, background, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an app that shows information and fetches Signal R messages every 5-10 seconds, and updates the information in real time as it changes

I have created a Background Service to detect if the app is in Background Mode, and if it is, i send a Local Notification to alert the user when a key change/update occurs.

Everything works flawlessly on the Simulator, if i put the app in background mode, i can see all the messages from SignalR coming on the Debug window

I added these Background fetch modes on Info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Everything works EXCEPT on a real iPhone. Debugging on foreground shows all the incoming messsages and updates, but as soon as i put the app on background, none of them show up.

I know i should use APN but it seems overkill for what im tryting to do. Besides, it works on simulator.

Comment: You are using http or https ? If you are using http, could you try to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  = true? like: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>`

Comment: Please try the setting above, if it works for you, please let me know, tks~

Comment: I already have thay key inside my info.plist :(

Comment: You are using http or https ?

Comment: We are currently using https

Comment: After investigating this issue in depth, I found that this issue is currently unsolvable. Here is the related link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252239/do-ios-apps-run-in-the-background